# Meaning of %04X in C and how to write the same in java

Tags: java, c

In the java project i am working on, some portion of the project was written previously by someone else in C and now i need to write the same in Java.

There is a statement in C code for printing to a file:

```
fprintf(ff, "%04X ", image[y*width+x]);
```

Firstly i am not sure about the meaning of `%04X`. I think it means that if `image[i]` has length five or more then print only leftmost four chararacters. To do the same in Java i thought about masking the value using `and` operation

```
 image[i] & 0xFFFF
```

Can someone please tell me the correct meaning of `%04X` and how to do the same in Java? Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The value is formatted as a hexadecimal integer with four digits and leading zeros. Java uses the same format string syntax. You can find it in the [javaDoc of `Formatter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html).

*Excerpt:*

```
'x', 'X'     integral    The result is formatted as a hexadecimal integer
```

A related functions are

```
// create a String with the formatted value.
String formatted = String.format("%04X ", image[y*width+x]);

// write a formatted value to the console (*)
System.out.printf("%04X ", image[y*width+x]);
```

<sub>(*) - write it to the `PrintStream` `System.out` which is *usually* the console but can be redirected to a file or something else</sub>

Answer (score 17):

Lets break the format code `"%04X"` into its separate parts:

- The `X` means that it will print an integer, in hexadecimal, large `X` for large hexadecimal letters
- The `4` means the number will be printed left justified with at least four digits, print spaces if there is less than four digits
- The `0` means that if there is less than four digits it will print leading zeroes.

Answer (score 2):

The X in %04X means hexadecimal, with ABCDEF instead of abcdef, and the 04 means print at *least* four digits, padding with leading zeros. It will use more digits if needed.

Answer (score 1):

Understand by Examples

```
printf ("%d", 75);   // Output ->   '75' (Decimal Number)
printf ("%X", 75);   // Output ->   '4B' (X for large hexadecimal letters)
printf ("%4X", 75);  // Output -> '  4B' (Left justified with 4 spaces)
printf ("%04X", 75); // Output -> '004B' (Left justified with 0 until 4 digits)
```